# Should I use mastic or thinset for ceramic tile backsplash in kitchen?

Tags: kitchens, tile, ceramic-tile, backsplash

I am about to install a tile backsplash in our kitchen, using [these tiles](http://americanolean.com/series.cfm?series=144), in 2" x 4" "mosaic" sheets.

When I tiled my bathroom I used thinset (unmodified on the floor and modified on the wall/shower) and I read a lot of info that said not to use mastic in a wet area.  But this current project is around the kitchen counters and stove, not really a "wet area".

I do have a little bit of modified thinset left from the last project, but I will need to buy more (or I could buy mastic instead).

Comment: Check out this question for some tips: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/9179/how-do-i-put-up-a-travertine-tile-backsplash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This close to a water source I'd recommend thinset.  You can't go wrong that way.
But you could probably get away with mastic if you really prefer it.

Comment: I ended up using thinset.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question but I simply must put the idea that using thin-set on walls is a good option. Thin set is a motar designed specifically for floor installation it's gritty doesn't stay on the wall well when applied. Now that isn't to say it won't work it will, provided you use a cement based backer board such as durarock or hardi-backer. But here is a key walls tend to move and swell more than floors do and thin-set being concrete and gritty isn't great at holding up to the stress. Even the modified/fortified variations have limits.

Mastic is designed for walls has outstanding bond and durability ease of application etc. And the only way water would be an issue is if it was soaked with it and remained so for weeks. In a kitchen that isn't a problem. I also use it for tile showers/tub splashes. Sheet rock isn't recommended for wet areas like showers and tub splashed but in a kitchen it's okay. Thin-set will not bond to sheet rock reliably. So if anyone decides to use it instead of mastic make sure you use a good cement based backer board.

Answer (score 0):

We use mastic on walls. First is the hardie backer board, second is the membrane, and here comes the mastic since it is the best. Plus when using a wet saw; every tile that has to be cut needs to be dry. Sometimes mastic takes 3 days to dry. Depending on how much you use. If everything is installed correctly then there shouldn't be any problems.